# Emacs documentation missing

Tags: raspbian, noobs

If I start up emacs without the GUI (without `startx`), using the `emacs` command, a buffer labeled *GNU Emacs* is displayed. On top it says "Welcome to GNU Emacs".

In this screen, there is a menu item labeled "Read the Emacs Manual". If I follow this link (or type the shortcut C-h r), it tells me "Info file emacs does not exist". On my mac, I can view this page.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install emacs`, but that just tells me I already have the latest version. I have also tried to guess other package names like emacs-doc, but to no avail.

Question: How to install the emacs documentation (using apt-get)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question was answered here: https://askubuntu.com/q/572026

The solution for me was

`sudo apt-get install emacs23-common-non-dfsg`

Note that maybe you should probably replace the `23` by the version you are running, though version 23 is probably the "default" version right now. To find your version of emacs simple do `emacs --version`.  After installing this package, the shortcut `C-h r` worked fine in emacs.